# How to build a static node.js that could get running in ubuntu8 without libc?

Tags: node.js, compilation, static

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.18.3

RUN apk update && apk add --update musl-dev gcc python3-dev py3-pip chrpath git vim mc wget make openssh-client patchelf

RUN mkdir /build /package
WORKDIR /build

RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.18.0/node-v18.18.0.tar.gz && tar -xzf node-v18.18.0.tar.gz
WORKDIR node-v18.18.0

RUN apk add linux-headers
RUN apk add build-base

RUN ./configure --enable-static --fully-static
#RUN make -j$(nproc) LDFLAGS="-static" LINKFORSHARED=" "
RUN make -j$(nproc)

# Then copy /build to host storage
```

I could get a 94MB node binary executable:

```
├── Release
│   ├── bytecode_builtins_list_generator
│   ├── cctest
│   ├── embedtest
│   ├── genccode
│   ├── gen-regexp-special-case
│   ├── icupkg
│   ├── mksnapshot
│   ├── node
│   ├── node_mksnapshot
│   ├── obj
│   ├── obj.target
│   ├── openssl-cli
│   ├── overlapped-checker
│   └── torque
```

When I run it in host, ubuntu22, it is working fine.

But when I put it into the ubuntu8, it raises errors:

```
root@ubuntu:~/test/node-v18.18.0/out/Release# ./node
./node[9432]: ../src/tracing/agent.cc:55:node::tracing::Agent::Agent(): Assertion `(uv_loop_init(&tracing_loop_)) == (0)' failed.
Aborted
```